# what is the purpose of site_key?

Tags: updating

In ROOT/modules/update/update.fetch.inc, there is the following code.

```
$site_key = drupal_hmac_base64($base_url, drupal_get_private_key());
$url = _update_build_fetch_url($project, $site_key);
```

[`_update_build_fetch_url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21update%21update.fetch.inc/function/_update_build_fetch_url/7.x) contains the following code.

```
  // Only append usage information if we have a site key and the project is
  // enabled. We do not want to record usage statistics for disabled projects.
  if (!empty($site_key) && (strpos($project['project_type'], 'disabled') === FALSE)) {
    // Append the site key.
    $url .= (strpos($url, '?') !== FALSE) ? '&' : '?';
    $url .= 'site_key=';
    $url .= rawurlencode($site_key);

    // Append the version.
    if (!empty($project['info']['version'])) {
      $url .= '&version=';
      $url .= rawurlencode($project['info']['version']);
    }

    // Append the list of modules or themes enabled.
    $list = array_keys($project['includes']);
    $url .= '&list=';
    $url .= rawurlencode(implode(',', $list));
  }
```

This function generates the URL to fetch information about project updates, returning a URL like http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/examples/7.x?site_key=FuSSIDdX3JtCJQV7F1hWK6WopklCLf0jjHFDC1Nevys&version=7.x-1.x-dev&list=ajax_example%2Cexamples.

Why does Drupal need site_key? How do I know the value of `$base_url` from site_key?

Answer (score 3):

It's a unique value that allows to identify the site asking for updates. It is used on Drupal.org when giving the number of site using a module, which is shown in every project page.

> [image: screenshot]

Without that value, Drupal.org could not report the number of sites using a module, since it could not understand which site is asking for updates.

Since site_key is a crypted hash derived from `$base_url`, you cannot get the value of `$base_url` from its hash; that is how hash works. Hashes are used to save the passwords in the database; nobody can get the value of the password from the hash saved in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a unique token for each site, that Drupal reports when checking for updates. So the statistics (below the releases there is a 'view usage statistics' link) are checked against a token. Otherwise if you would check for updates 100 times, there would be in increased usage for all your modules.

So it enhances accuracy on Drupal.org backed.